# Using Power Query to Eliminate "Cancelled" Order Duplication or "Removing Specific Duplicate Entries"

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates, transform

In my table , each '**OrderNo**' should ideally be unique. However, errors in CustomerID assignment have led to order cancellations and subsequent reentries with the same 'OrderNo' under correct CustomerIDs. Consequently, I now have duplicate 'OrderNo' entries with one marked 'Cancelled' and another indicating 'Open' or 'Closed' in the field "StatusDesc". I need to eliminate these 'Cancelled' entries, thereby leaving only the valid 'Open' or 'Closed' orders in cases of 'OrderNo' duplication.
[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5dIK.png)
[Needed Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDK1z.png)
Here is a sample of my data:

| OrderNo | StatusDesc | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101992 | Cancelled | MG IMAGING |
| 101992 | Closed | SWISS CROWN |
| 101281 | Open | JLL/MOODYS |
| 101281 | Cancelled | MOODY'S |
| 102083 | Open | DUGGAL-BKLYN |
| 102082 | Open | CHB |
| 102084 | Open | NEWMARK |
| 102080 | Cancelled | WILLETT ADV |

Here is the needed result which correctly removes the orders 101992 and 101281 which were duplicated and had the statusdesc of cancel:

| OrderNo | StatusDesc | CustomerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101992 | Closed | SWISS CROWN |
| 101281 | Open | JLL/MOODYS |
| 102083 | Open | DUGGAL-BKLYN |
| 102082 | Open | CHB |
| 102084 | Open | NEWMARK |
| 102080 | Cancelled | WILLETT ADV |

I can easily use the "Show Duplicates" option in Power Query to identify the duplicates but I can't seem to figure where to go to get the result I'm looking for.

Hope someone can advise me as I am new to Power Query but am a quick learner and I need to solve this onging problem!

Thanks in advance.

Michelle

I tried using "Show Duplicates" and Group the orderno which allowed me to also see duplicates. But I don't know how to "delete" the records or what the best approach to solve this problem as I need the table to only delete cancelled orders for those that are duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the above task using `Power Query` follow the steps:

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1

---

- Next, open a blank query from `Data Tab` --> `Get & Transform Data` --> `Get Data` --> `From Other Sources` --> `Blank Query`

---

- The above lets the `Power Query` window opens, now from `Home` Tab --> `Advanced Editor` --> And paste the following `M-Code` by removing whatever you see, and press **Done**

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"OrderNo"}, {{"All", each _, type table [OrderNo=number, StatusDesc=text, CustomerID=text]}, {"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"StatusDesc", "CustomerID"}, {"StatusDesc", "CustomerID"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded All", "Custom", each if [StatusDesc] = "Cancelled" and [Count] >= 2 then null else [StatusDesc]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] <> null and [Custom] <> ""),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Count", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to `Excel` --> Click on `Close & Load` or `Close & Load To` --> The first one which clicked shall create a new sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---